# How to connect to SSH host from Docker container running on SSH remote

Tags: docker, ssh, portforwarding

I run applications on both SSH host and remote PC. A client application runs in a Docker container on the remote. A server application runs on the host.
I want the client app to connect to the server app.

[image: 1]

Host: Windows 10
Remote: Ubuntu 18.04

I connect to SSH remote using remote port forwarding like this.

```
ssh user@address -i xxx.pem -R 54321:localhost:54321
```

And run the Docker container on the SSH remote like this.

```
docker run -it -p 54321:54321 some_container bash
```

Then, I got this error.

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:54321: bind: address already in use.
```

How do I solve this?

I tried to use iptables instead of "docker -p". But I don't know what I describe.

Comment: Something is already using port 54321 on the remote machine. Do you have a stopped container that's blocking it? You can see stopped containers using `docker ps -a`. If you have one, then do `docker rm <container name>` and the port should be available again.

Comment: @HansKilian I removed all of containers and ran the container again. But I got same error. “ss -ap” showed that sshd was listening on 127.0.0.1:54321. It may be for port forwarding. Is it impossible?